# What may be the problem with this cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I've been having this issue for quite some time now and I can't find a solution, I've tried so many things that I've lost track, but after some research it seems that it might have something to do with my processor (too old perhaps?), I started with machine learning for a proyect just this year so i'm not experienced at all

System specs
- AMD Phenom II X4 955
- ASUS M5A78L-M/USB3 (AM3R2)
- EVGA NVIDIA GeForce GT 740 (2Gb)
- 14 Gb RAM
- Windows 10 Pro
- CUDA kit 10.1
- Nvidia Driver 441.20
- Tensorflow 2.0.0 = tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64 (build for legacy cpu without AVX

I'm running a example script from keras's web page for Convolutional filter visualization:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image as pil_image
from keras.preprocessing.image import save_img
from keras import layers
from keras.applications import vgg16
from keras import backend as K


def normalize(x):
    """utility function to normalize a tensor.

    # Arguments
        x: An input tensor.

    # Returns
        The normalized input tensor.
    """
    return x / (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(x))) + K.epsilon())


def deprocess_image(x):
    """utility function to convert a float array into a valid uint8 image.

    # Arguments
        x: A numpy-array representing the generated image.

    # Returns
        A processed numpy-array, which could be used in e.g. imshow.
    """
    # normalize tensor: center on 0., ensure std is 0.25
    x -= x.mean()
    x /= (x.std() + K.epsilon())
    x *= 0.25

    # clip to [0, 1]
    x += 0.5
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 1)

    # convert to RGB array
    x *= 255
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        x = x.transpose((1, 2, 0))
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
    return x


def process_image(x, former):
    """utility function to convert a valid uint8 image back into a float array.
       Reverses `deprocess_image`.

    # Arguments
        x: A numpy-array, which could be used in e.g. imshow.
        former: The former numpy-array.
                Need to determine the former mean and variance.

    # Returns
        A processed numpy-array representing the generated image.
    """
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        x = x.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    return (x / 255 - 0.5) * 4 * former.std() + former.mean()


def visualize_layer(model,
                    layer_name,
                    step=1.,
                    epochs=15,
                    upscaling_steps=9,
                    upscaling_factor=1.2,
                    output_dim=(412, 412),
                    filter_range=(0, None)):
    """Visualizes the most relevant filters of one conv-layer in a certain model.

    # Arguments
        model: The model containing layer_name.
        layer_name: The name of the layer to be visualized.
                    Has to be a part of model.
        step: step size for gradient ascent.
        epochs: Number of iterations for gradient ascent.
        upscaling_steps: Number of upscaling steps.
                         Starting image is in this case (80, 80).
        upscaling_factor: Factor to which to slowly upgrade
                          the image towards output_dim.
        output_dim: [img_width, img_height] The output image dimensions.
        filter_range: Tupel[lower, upper]
                      Determines the to be computed filter numbers.
                      If the second value is `None`,
                      the last filter will be inferred as the upper boundary.
    """

    def _generate_filter_image(input_img,
                               layer_output,
                               filter_index):
        """Generates image for one particular filter.

        # Arguments
            input_img: The input-image Tensor.
            layer_output: The output-image Tensor.
            filter_index: The to be processed filter number.
                          Assumed to be valid.

        #Returns
            Either None if no image could be generated.
            or a tuple of the image (array) itself and the last loss.
        """
        s_time = time.time()

        # we build a loss function that maximizes the activation
        # of the nth filter of the layer considered
        if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
            loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, filter_index, :, :])
        else:
            loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])

        # we compute the gradient of the input picture wrt this loss
        grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]

        # normalization trick: we normalize the gradient
        grads = normalize(grads)

        # this function returns the loss and grads given the input picture
        iterate = K.function([input_img], [loss, grads])

        # we start from a gray image with some random noise
        intermediate_dim = tuple(
            int(x / (upscaling_factor ** upscaling_steps)) for x in output_dim)
        if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
            input_img_data = np.random.random(
                (1, 3, intermediate_dim[0], intermediate_dim[1]))
        else:
            input_img_data = np.random.random(
                (1, intermediate_dim[0], intermediate_dim[1], 3))
        input_img_data = (input_img_data - 0.5) * 20 + 128

        # Slowly upscaling towards the original size prevents
        # a dominating high-frequency of the to visualized structure
        # as it would occur if we directly compute the 412d-image.
        # Behaves as a better starting point for each following dimension
        # and therefore avoids poor local minima
        for up in reversed(range(upscaling_steps)):
            # we run gradient ascent for e.g. 20 steps
            for _ in range(epochs):
                loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
                input_img_data += grads_value * step

                # some filters get stuck to 0, we can skip them
                if loss_value <= K.epsilon():
                    return None

            # Calculate upscaled dimension
            intermediate_dim = tuple(
                int(x / (upscaling_factor ** up)) for x in output_dim)
            # Upscale
            img = deprocess_image(input_img_data[0])
            img = np.array(pil_image.fromarray(img).resize(intermediate_dim,
                                                           pil_image.BICUBIC))
            input_img_data = np.expand_dims(
                process_image(img, input_img_data[0]), 0)

        # decode the resulting input image
        img = deprocess_image(input_img_data[0])
        e_time = time.time()
        print('Costs of filter {:3}: {:5.0f} ( {:4.2f}s )'.format(filter_index,
                                                                  loss_value,
                                                                  e_time - s_time))
        return img, loss_value

    def _draw_filters(filters, n=None):
        """Draw the best filters in a nxn grid.

        # Arguments
            filters: A List of generated images and their corresponding losses
                     for each processed filter.
            n: dimension of the grid.
               If none, the largest possible square will be used
        """
        if n is None:
            n = int(np.floor(np.sqrt(len(filters))))

        # the filters that have the highest loss are assumed to be better-looking.
        # we will only keep the top n*n filters.
        filters.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        filters = filters[:n * n]

        # build a black picture with enough space for
        # e.g. our 8 x 8 filters of size 412 x 412, with a 5px margin in between
        MARGIN = 5
        width = n * output_dim[0] + (n - 1) * MARGIN
        height = n * output_dim[1] + (n - 1) * MARGIN
        stitched_filters = np.zeros((width, height, 3), dtype='uint8')

        # fill the picture with our saved filters
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                img, _ = filters[i * n + j]
                width_margin = (output_dim[0] + MARGIN) * i
                height_margin = (output_dim[1] + MARGIN) * j
                stitched_filters[
                    width_margin: width_margin + output_dim[0],
                    height_margin: height_margin + output_dim[1], :] = img

        # save the result to disk
        save_img('vgg_{0:}_{1:}x{1:}.png'.format(layer_name, n), stitched_filters)

    # this is the placeholder for the input images
    assert len(model.inputs) == 1
    input_img = model.inputs[0]

    # get the symbolic outputs of each "key" layer (we gave them unique names).
    layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers[1:]])

    output_layer = layer_dict[layer_name]
    assert isinstance(output_layer, layers.Conv2D)

    # Compute to be processed filter range
    filter_lower = filter_range[0]
    filter_upper = (filter_range[1]
                    if filter_range[1] is not None
                    else len(output_layer.get_weights()[1]))
    assert(filter_lower >= 0
           and filter_upper <= len(output_layer.get_weights()[1])
           and filter_upper > filter_lower)
    print('Compute filters {:} to {:}'.format(filter_lower, filter_upper))

    # iterate through each filter and generate its corresponding image
    processed_filters = []
    for f in range(filter_lower, filter_upper):
        img_loss = _generate_filter_image(input_img, output_layer.output, f)

        if img_loss is not None:
            processed_filters.append(img_loss)

    print('{} filter processed.'.format(len(processed_filters)))
    # Finally draw and store the best filters to disk
    _draw_filters(processed_filters)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # the name of the layer we want to visualize
    # (see model definition at keras/applications/vgg16.py)
    LAYER_NAME = 'block5_conv1'

    # build the VGG16 network with ImageNet weights
    vgg = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    print('Model loaded.')
    vgg.summary()

    # example function call
    visualize_layer(vgg, LAYER_NAME)
```

After running the code I get this traceback:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2019-11-14 20:13:01.475103: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2019-11-14 20:13:05.119364: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2019-11-14 20:13:05.296509: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 740 major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.202
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-11-14 20:13:05.296858: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2019-11-14 20:13:05.304775: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-14 20:13:05.309845: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 740 major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.202
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-11-14 20:13:05.310274: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2019-11-14 20:13:05.318573: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Mi unidad\Code testin\NewTest.py", line 247, in <module>
    vgg = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\applications\__init__.py", line 20, in wrapper
    return base_fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\applications\vgg16.py", line 11, in VGG16
    return vgg16.VGG16(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras_applications\vgg16.py", line 112, in VGG16
    name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 463, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 141, in build
    constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 279, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape, dtype=dtype),
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 227, in __call__
    dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 4357, in random_uniform
    shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=seed)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 5598, in random_uniform
    shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=seed)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\random_ops.py", line 237, in random_uniform
    shape = tensor_util.shape_tensor(shape)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 964, in shape_tensor
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtype, name="shape")
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1184, in convert_to_tensor
    return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1242, in convert_to_tensor_v2
    as_ref=False)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1296, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 286, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 227, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 95, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    ctx.ensure_initialized()
  File "C:\Users\SEBA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\context.py", line 492, in ensure_initialized
    self._context_handle = pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_NewContext(opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found.
```

I also run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", 
len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

And get:

```
2019-11-14 20:46:58.806642: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2019-11-14 20:47:02.876517: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2019-11-14 20:47:02.914412: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 740 major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.202
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-11-14 20:47:02.914794: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2019-11-14 20:47:02.915417: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: Num GPUs Available:  1
0
```

I hope someone can help, I really need this to work
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your GPU is not supported by CUDA, and therefore is having issues with TensorFlow (hence why TensorFlow isn't recognizing your GPU).

According to [NVIDIA's GPU documentation](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) site, your GPU's compute compatibility is 3.0. However, according to [TensorFlow's docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), a CUDA device with compute compatibility >= 3.5 is needed.

I suggest using TensorFlow with CPU instead of GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

> According to NVIDIA's GPU documentation site, your GPU's compute compatibility is 3.0. However, according to TensorFlow's docs, a CUDA device with compute compatibility >= 3.5 is needed.

After reading that I started researching and found this:  https://medium.com/@mccann.matt/compiling-tensorflow-with-cuda-3-0-support-42d8fe0bf3b5
on how to compile a tensorflow version compatible with compute capability 3.0, it might be painfull to do but a want to use GPU to train a CNN with a very large dataset, so i think it's worth the try.
I'll post an update if it works or not.
Thanks for pointing that out :)